# Why can a MongoDb cursor be indexed as if it was an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I noticed that if I execute a JavaScript script using the `mongo` command, the script can treat a cursor object as if it was an array.

```
var conn = new Mongo('localhost:27017');
var db = conn.getDB('learn');
db.test.remove({});
db.test.insert({foo: 'bar'});
var cur = db.test.find();
print(cur[0].foo);   //prints: bar
print(cur[1]); // prints: undefined
```

This seems like it should be beyond the capabilities of the JavaScript language, since there is no way to "overload the subscript operator".  So how does this actually work?

Comment: Every document can be accessed by its index... if you access beyond the number of documents, it returns "undefined"

Comment: It may not manipulate the operator, but it can manipulate the indexes. Since they're just a subset of properties, they can be [defined as getters and/or setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). `Object.defineProperty(cursor, '0', { get: ... });`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski But without "method missing" it would have to define an operator for every index, which doesn't seem practical here..

Comment: @user2864740 No, it probably isn't practical with access to native code as dt0xff mentioned. But, I was mainly pointing out that it is possible to define an array-like object without operator overloading.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, it is not a case. Just look at cursor class https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/query.js , here we have no logic similar to this one and this is what I checked first, but it will be stupid for mongo to do this, yea. But it can be handy for some cases if you are trying to emulate this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documentation says, [it is special ability of driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#iterator-index). It *automagicly* converts `cursor[0]` to `cursor.toArray()[0]`. You can prove it by overriding `toArray()` with print function or `new Error().stack` to get callstack back. Here it is:

```
at DBQuery.a.toArray ((shell):1:32)
at DBQuery.arrayAccess (src/mongo/shell/query.js:290:17)
at (shell):1:2
```

As you can see, indexing calls `arrayAccess`. How? [Here we have a `dbQueryIndexAccess` function](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/scripting/v8_db.cpp#L650), which calls `arrayAccess`.

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> arrayAccess = info.This()->GetPrototype()->ToObject()->Get(
                v8::String::New("arrayAccess"));
...
v8::Handle<v8::Function> f = arrayAccess.As<v8::Function>();
...
return f->Call(info.This(), 1, argv);
```

And [here we have a code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/scripting/engine_v8.cpp#L1254), which sets **indexed property handler** to this function. WOW, v8 API gives us ability to add this handler!

```
DBQueryFT()->InstanceTemplate()->SetIndexedPropertyHandler(dbQueryIndexAccess);
```

... and injects it into JS cursor class, which is defined originaly in JS.

```
injectV8Function("DBQuery", DBQueryFT(), _global);
```

**Tl;dr**: It is *hacked* in C++ source code of mongo shell.